# Get Active Directory user from client request, server side?

Tags: iis, active-directory, httpmodule

I have a custom HTTP Module running on IIS 7.5, and the requests will be coming from different machines in the same Active Directory environment. **Is it possible** for me to get the current user (their AD Name?) from a request (or look up, if I knew the LDAP path?) in an HTTP Module running server side?

I'm not AD expert, but I've looked through the different properties that come through the `HTTPApplication` instance (see below) within my module, and I'm not seeing anything obvious.

```
Private Sub AuthenticateRequest(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        Dim oHttpApplication As HttpApplication = CType(sender, HttpApplication)
        '...
        ' Get AD Info from oHttpApplication.Request?
        '...
End Sub
```

Does anyone know if this is possible or know of a way to accomplish this?

**UPDATE:**

I've added my solution below.

Comment: ... A comment after a down vote would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution - in VB.NET:

```
Dim username As String = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name
```

**NOTE:** The answer to the question in my link goes on to use a `PrincipalContext` and `UserPrincipal` object, but for my scenario all I needed was the username. I would also like to point out that when testing that solution, this line:

```
pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "active.directory.domain.com")
```

Also works fine without the domain for me:

```
pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)
```

So hopefully this will be helpful to someone in the future!

Answer (score 0):

**Modify IIS settings:**

In IIS **disable** anonymous authentication and **enable** windows authentication.

**Modify Web application config file:**

Enable impersonation

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**C# Code:**

```
using System.Security.Principal


var user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

Comment: Thank you. I've tried that though. For me, it returns the user tied to  the ApplicationPoolIdentity account running on the server. I need to know who is sending the request (i.e. from the client).

Comment: I've modified my answer. If the user is in the same LAN this should work.

Comment: Thanks again - but I already had impersonation set up. Please see my solution that I found.